# How to set delivery format while using SMTP client?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am trying to access the **DeliveryFormat** property of the SMPTPClient object while programatically sending email. However, it is not recognized. I checked the MSDN documentation, which do not indicate that it has been deprecated.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International; //DeliveryFormat property is not recognised
```

Is there a new way to set the delivery format property?

Comment: Shouldn't that be "smtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;"?

Comment: Yea I changed that.. but that's not the issue

Comment: Well it should be " = **Smtp**DeliveryFormat.International". If that does not help, which version of .NET you are using?

Comment: Thats also not the issue, problem is that the DeliveryFormat property is itself not recognised. It is asking me the standard "Are you missing an assmbly reference" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it's been deprecated, it's that it's too new for the version you're targeting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliveryformat(v=vs.110).aspx

> Version Information
>   .NET Framework
>   Available **since 4.5**

(emphasis mine)

Change your project to target the .NET Framework 4.5 and it will work.

This does of course mean you need to be running Visual Studio 2012 or later. If you're running 2015 then consider targeting 4.6.1.